# How to install Windows 8 without flash drive and dvd? GPT/UEFI

Tags: windows-8, boot, partitioning, uefi, gpt

I have my new SSD, on which I want to install Windows 8.1. I have an iso image.

So what I normally do when I use MBR on the drive:

1. Create partitions
2. Extract iso to one of the partitions
3. Make that partition active using diskpart or diskmgmt.msc
4. It loads the installer and I can install to any empty other partition

And I am done, everything is cool and takes almost no time to install.

However now I tried to do same thing but using GPT and UEFI, and this is some nightmare, I cannot find any information on how to install the Windows from the same GPT drive on UEFI. Can anybody tell how it should be done on GPT/UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

I would install from a virtual CD ROM which you can **[get from here](http://download.cnet.com/Virtual-CloneDrive/3000-20432_4-173879.html)** - or any other if you have a preference.

It looks like the old 7zip trick to reveal the .exe does not work.

Comment: How is he going to boot and use that virtual CDROM? With a blank fresh SSD there is no OS yet.

Comment: He is obviously doing it from a running OS, else he could not have done all the things he stated.

Comment: even with running OS you cannot do it. I remember times when I could start installation of Windows XP to another drive, but now setup tries to update current Windows installation - it doesn't allow you to choose fresh installation to chosen drive.